# Using Windows device name such as Con as Java class name

Tags: java

I am referring to my previous question but this time I used the java compiler and the compiler compiles the output- it gives a weird output. And this time I used `this` instead of `super`.

[image]

This is the code of the program.

```
class Con {
    int x = 10;
    Con() {
        this(2);
        System.out.println("x :" + x);
    }
    Con(int i) {
        x = i;
        System.out.println("x :" + x);
    }   
}

class DemoCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Con c1 = new Con();
    }
}
```

What do you think is the problem here? Is this a bug in Java?

Java version - 1.6.0 JDK

I used Eclipse to run the program and there is a Class not found exception. 
`A.java` is the file name... We did a minor edit and made a public class called `A.java` too but the results are same. We further found out that the problem lies in the compiler.

Comment: Running it how?  If your file is called `A.java` you need a public class called `A`.

Comment: Does javac do this for every file or just `A.java`?  Someone could have replaced your `javac.exe` :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Windows it seems CON is reserved name and cannot be used for folders/directories or **filenames**.

The following

```
print "test" > Con.java
```

is not working.

Therefor the compiler is unable to create your Con.class and crashes.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Do not use the following reserved device names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended

Comment: Is this problem something occurring in every version of Windows or is just Windows 7?

Comment: @Duli-chan: This goes back to the ages of DOS. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations

Comment: It is __both__ intentional behavior and a problem.

Answer (score 7):

perhaps the problem exists because `CON` is a reserved file name (it was on MS-DOS  -- see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/31157 http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm)

Comment: It sure was the problem... Are there anymore problems with class naming like that ....

Comment: 'LPT1' 'COM1' 'NUL' etc are reserved MS-DOS device names

Answer (score 3):

How did you compile it? On Win7 32b with Java 1.6 I get:

> Type name is not valid. 'Con' is an invalid name on this platform.

Comment: Because `con` is a restricted name on Windows. http://www.hoax-slayer.com/con-folder-name.shtml

Comment: In Eclipse I get: _A class file was not written. The project may be inconsistent, if so try refreshing this project and building it_

Answer (score 2):

Yes it looks like a bug. It compiled very well on my

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11A511)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-383, mixed mode)
```

environment on Mac OS X.

Maybe we can help further if you tell us whether you are using Sun (Oracle) JDK or OpenJDK?

Problem might be about class name (`Con`) and file name (`A`) are different (they should be the same) and you have two classes at the same level in a single file. Anyway, it compiles well on my box.

Comment: I am using the Sun JDK... We tried in two different machines and the result is very same. More than that there is a weird beeping sound!

Comment: As I recall, the class name need only match the file name when the class is public. It is OK for two or more classes to be in a single file, but only one can have public scope.

Comment: @Duli-chan The beeping sound might be the 'beep' character, when the system "prints" character code 7.

Comment: The issue is that javac is trying to create the file `Con.class`, which isn't allowed on Windows for MS-DOS compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In java, the class name and file name must be **exactly** the same. In your case, your class name is `Con`, therefore, your class file **must** be `Con.java`. Since `DemoCon` is your class with the `static void main(String[] args)`, your java file must be `DemoCon.java`.

Comment: It's same over here. After changing it also it's not working over here.

Comment: We have two machines over here that gives this exact beeping sound~~

Comment: @Duli-chan, then explain **fully** to us how you setup your machine and development environment.

Comment: We found the problem it's with Windows 7 about the Con class name. We still looking at the problem though...

Comment: The source file naming constraint only applies to `public` classes - a Java source file can declare at most one top-level `public` class or interface, and if it has one, its name must match the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I saved your code as   `DemoCon.java .`

and ran it as

```
javac DemoCon.java 

java DemoCon
```

o/p was

```
 x :2
    x :2
```

Comment: Another machine gives this output over here two. But we have two machines that gives the same exact output^^